# HTML- multiple incorrect alignment horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to align the site logo, site name and site header horizontally but they go all to different places.[image]

I want it something like this: [image]

The html and css is here https://codepen.io/jonathan-lau/pen/jpJBMK

I've `display: inline-block;` but it's still not aligned correctly.

This is my ideal view except the logo and the site name are not aligned.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer below. I have updated your layout and css code. it works fine now. Cheers !!!

Comment: @VSM just tested it but the results is the same as the issue I have.

Comment: explain the issue... check code snippet.I think you check wrong answer ,not mine.

Comment: In snippet it works great but when I tried to save it as html and ran it it Internet explorer, it's not correctly aligned. The alignment is the same as the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
 .clearfix {
     display: inline-block;
}
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
 * html .clearfix {
     height: 1%;
}
 .clearfix {
     display: block;
}
/* close commented backslash hack */
 body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background: whitesmoke;
}
 .site-header{
     padding:10px 5%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     position:relative;
}
 .main-logo{
     img {
         size: 5px;
    }
}
 .site-name{
     font-size: 20px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 21px 32px 0;
}
 .billboard{
     text-align:right;
     padding: 10px 5%;
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 20px;
}
 .box__input{
     text-align:right;
}
 .search-box{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -10px;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,50%);
     background: #2F3640;
     height: 40px;
     border-radius: 40px;
     padding:10px;
}
 .search-box:hover .search-txt{
     width: 320px;
     padding: 0 6px;
}
 .search-box:hover .search-btn{
     background: white;
}
.search-box .wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
 .search-btn{
     color: #e84118;
     float: right;
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #2F3640;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     transition: 0.4s;
     position:absolute;
     top: 0;
     right:0;
}
 .search-txt{
     border: none;
     background: none;
     outline: none;
     float: left;
     padding: 0;
     color: white;
     font-size: 15px;
     transition: 0.4s;
     line-height: 40px;
     width: 0px;
     min-width: 40px;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
main section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DCS text analytics tool</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sprint12.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="site-header clearfix">
            <div class="main-logo">
                <a href="sprint12.html">
                    <img src="sample logo.jpg" alt="logo">            
                </a>
                <p class="site-name clearfix">DCS text analytics tool</p>        
           </div>
           <div class="search-box">
             <div class="wrapper">
               <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="">
               <a class="search-btn" href="#">
                 <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
               </a>
             </div>
            </div> 
        </header>
        <main>
            <section>
               <h1 class="billboard clearfix">
                   Choose a file or drag it here:
               </h1>
               <form class="box" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div class="box__input">
                    <input class="box__file" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
                    <label for="file"><strong></strong> <span class="box__dragndrop"> </span></label>
                    <button class="box__button" type="submit">Upload</button>
                 </div>
            </form>
            </section>
            
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/yqb6ez4L/24/

This works for you. Try and let me know if there is any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan , There is no issue. it works fine..Explain. thanks.

Comment: In snippet it works great but when I tried to save it as html and ran it it Internet explorer, it's not correctly aligned. The alignment is the same as the screenshot attached

Comment: @Jonathan, try this fiddle and let me know about result. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/yqb6ez4L/40/

Comment: the logo and the site name still are still not aligned together. The site name is slightly lower than the logo.

Comment: @Jonathan, please create a new fiddle, applying your logo, without that I couldn't fix the problem.send me the link asap.

Comment: I've added the screenshot on the original question for visual purpose.https://jsfiddle.net/claud_2723/qtgdnxvL/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've centered the content in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjgZLZ

For the logo I used `test-align`, for the other `margin: 0 auto` combined with a fixed width.

Comment: @Baas, with content being centered, the text and the search box were overlapping

Comment: That is because you use `position: absolute;` on your search box with `top: 30%;` this percentage gives issues when the screen has a small height. Defining for example `top: 200px;` would fix this. I've updated the codepen accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox properties, instead. Please take a look at this pen which I've forked from yours : https://codepen.io/muratdogan17/pen/RBdpQV

```
.main-wrapper {
  align-items:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Complete css flexbox guide : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Codepen html section parses directly body, that's why you do not need to write extra meta or doctype staff, btw.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```css
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
  }
  .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
  /* start commented backslash hack \*/
  * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
  .clearfix { display: block; }
  /* close commented backslash hack */

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: whitesmoke;
}

.site-header {
    padding: 10px 5%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-logo{
    img{
        size: 5px;
    }
}
main {
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.site-name{
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 21px 32px 0;
           
}
.billboard{
    padding: 10px 5%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.box__input{
    
    text-align:right;
}

.search-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%,50%);
    background: #2F3640;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding:10px;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-txt{
    width: 320px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-btn{
    background: white;
}
.search-btn{
    color: #e84118;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2F3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-txt{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;
 }
form.box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DCS text analytics tool</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sprint12.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="site-header clearfix">
            <div class="main-logo">
                <a href="sprint12.html">
                    <img src="sample logo.jpg" alt="logo">            
                </a>
            <p class="site-name clearfix">DCS text analytics tool</p>        
           </div>
          <main>
            <section>
               <h1 class="billboard clearfix">
                   Choose a file or drag it here:
               </h1>
            </section> <!-- This is a commen-->
            <form class="box" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div class="box__input">
                    <input class="box__file" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
                    <label for="file"><strong></strong> <span class="box__dragndrop"> </span></label>
                    <button class="box__button" type="submit">Upload</button>
                 </div>
            </form>
            
            <div class="search-box">
                        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="">
                        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </a>
            </div> 
        </main>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the alignment issue is still there which is the same as what I've attached in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add to left side section float:left; width:auto; and right section float:right; width:auto;

Answer (score 0):

This solution fixes the alignment on a desktop computer. I also made some corrections in semantics, you used a `h1` for an input field and a `p` for the page title etc.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

/*Header*/
.site-header {
  padding: 10px 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-logo img {
    size: 5px;
}

.site-name {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 0;
}

.billboard {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.box__input {
  text-align: right;
}

/*Main*/
.main-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  background: #2F3640;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #e84118;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2F3640;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DCS text analytics tool</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sprint12.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="site-header">
    
    <div class="main-logo">
      <a href="sprint12.html">
        <img src="sample/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <h1 class="site-name">DCS text analytics tool</h1>
    </div>
    
    <section >
      <p class="billboard">
        Choose a file or drag it here:
      </p>

      <form class="box" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="float: right;">
        <div class="box__input">
          <input class="box__file" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="">
          <label for="file"> <span class="box__dragndrop"> </span></label>
          <button class="box__button" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
    
  </header>


  <main class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="search-box">
      <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="">
      <a class="search-btn" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```